# How would I write this SQL query in Rails 3.2 syntax?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following code my Track.rb model. Is there any way to write this using more Rails syntax? Im using Rails 3.2

```
@track = Track.find(7)


Submission.joins("LEFT JOIN missions ON missions.id = submissions.mission_id")
          .joins("LEFT JOIN tracks ON tracks.id = missions.track_id")
          .where("missions.track_id = ?", track.id)
```

Models:

```
Track.rb
   has_many :missions

Mission.rb
   belongs_to :track
   has_many :submissions

Submission.rb
   belongs_to :mission
```

Comment: Do you have relationships between these models? If so, `includes` is the way to go.

Comment: Yea all my models are set up properly

Comment: If they are you can exercise those `belongs_to` type relationships by eager-loading the data you need. `includes` has the effect of adding a join without all the mess of re-defining what's involved. Experiment a bit and see what queries it generates. You can also set up `has_many :missions, through: tracks` and such to make a proper relationship for this in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you really need left join for `missions`? You filter by `missions.track_id`, so you do not need submissions without missions. Inner join would be more appropriate in this case.

Next, why do you need to join `tracks` - you do not use this table in the next sql.

With these thoughts, you could rewrite your code as:

```
Submission.joins(:mission).where(missions: { track_id: track.id })
```